# Loop through multiple links from an Excel file, open and download the corresponding webpages

Tags: html, r, loops, url, download

I downloaded from MediaCloud an Excel file with 1719 links to different newspaper articles. I am trying to use R to loop through each link, open it and download all the corresponding online articles in a single searchable file (HTML, CSV, TXT, PDF - doesn't matter) that I can read and analyze later.

I went through all similar questions on Stack Overflow and a number of tutorials for downloading files and managed to assemble this code (I am very new to R):

```
express <-read.csv("C://Users//julir//Documents//Data//express.csv")  
library(curl)  
for (express$url in 2:1720)   
destfile <- paste0("C://Users//julir//Documents//Data//results.csv")  
download.file(express$url, destfile, method = "auto", quiet = TRUE, cacheOK=TRUE)
```

Whenever I try to run it though I get the following error:

```
Error in download.file(express$url, destfile = express$url, method = "auto", : 'url' must be a length-one character vector
```

I tried also this alternative method suggested online:

```
library(httr)
url <- express$url  
response <- GET(express$url)  
html_document <- content(response, type = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

But I get the same mistake:

```
Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

So I guess there is a problem with how the URLs are stored - but I can't understand how to fix it.

I am also not certain about the downloading process - I would ideally want all text on the HTML page - it seems unpractical to use selectors and rvest in this case - but I might be very wrong.

Comment: Could you supply a sample of how your links are ordered in the excel file? As i see it, it seems like your for loop is the problem. Read the excel file into R with `readxl` or something, and try looping over the url's like this `for(url in url_file){ download code here }`. As is now, `express$url` in your code could be all the links being crammed into the download function, hence the error `must be length-one character vector` which means "Supply me with only one url"

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this!  All links are in the same column under the heading url. There are 1720 rows altogether. The info I get as info from R when I read the document is:   ``` Rows: 1720 Columns: 10                                                                                                 
-- Column specification ------
Delimiter: ","
chr (7): publish_date, title, url, language, themes, media_name, media_url
dbl (2): stories_id, media_id
lgl (1): ap_syndicated```   I tried running the code like this: ```for(url in express){download code}```  but got the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to look through the url's and read/parse each individually. You are essentially passing an array of urls into one request, which is why you see that error.

I don't know your content/urls, but here's an example of how you would approach this:

```
library(xml2)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(page_n = 1:5, urls = sprintf('https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/list/?page=%s', 1:5))

result_info <- lapply(df$urls, function(i){
  
  raw <- read_html(i) 
  a_tags <- raw %>% xml_find_all(".//a[contains(@href,'factchecks/2021')]")
  urls <- xml2::url_absolute(xml_attr(a_tags, "href"),xml_url(raw))
  titles <- xml_text(a_tags) %>% stri_trim_both()
  data.frame(title = titles, links = urls)
  
}) %>% rbind_pages()

result_info %>% head()
```

| title | links |
| --- | --- |
| Says of UW-Madison, "It cost the university $50k (your tax dollars) to remove" a rock considered by some a symbol of racism. | https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/aug/14/rachel-campos-duffy/no-taxpayer-funds-were-not-used-remove-rock-deemed/ |
| “Rand Paul’s medical license was just revoked!” | https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/aug/13/facebook-posts/no-rand-pauls-medical-license-wasnt-revoked/ |
| Every time outgoing New York Gov. Andrew Cuomo “says the firearm industry ‘is immune from lawsuits,’ it's false.” | https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/aug/13/elise-stefanik/refereeing-andrew-cuomo-elise-stefanik-firearm-ind/ |
| The United States' southern border is "basically open" and is "a super spreader event.” | https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/aug/13/gary-sides/north-carolina-school-leader-repeats-false-claims-/ |
| There is a “0.05% chance of dying from COVID.” | https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/aug/13/tiktok-posts/experts-break-down-numbers-catching-or-dying-covid/ |
| The Biden administration is “not even testing these people” being released by Border Patrol into the U.S. | https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/aug/13/ken-paxton/biden-administration-not-even-testing-migrants-rel/ |

Comment: Thank you so much! I see now what the problem was! I spent the day exploring the different elements of the code you suggested and just managed to run it with my data. However, now I get "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404." That's what I ran: ```destfile <- lapply(df$url, function(i){
  raw <- read_html(i) 
  a_tags <- raw %>% 
  xml_find_all(".//a[contains(@href,'co.uk/news')]")
  urls <- xml2::url_absolute(xml_attr(a_tags, "href"),xml_url(raw))
  titles <- xml_text(a_tags) %>% stri_trim_both()
  data.frame(title = titles, links = url)
  }) %>% rbind_pages()```

Comment: @julir a 404 error means a url was not reachable. So if this was an error on your data, it's probable that one of the urls is invalid in your dataset... Meaning it may have been removed over time etc. A way to get around this is to wrap the code inside of lapply in what's called a ?tryCatch. Basically the idea is "try this function, if there's an error, catch it and do something, but don't break(unless you want it to". So : `tryCatch(read_html(url), error = function(e)NA)` but all your code that processes the html goes in the try part. I'm on mobile so excuse formatting here.